# Get a list of observable properties

Tags: oop, matlab, properties, observer-pattern

i know how to use the command 'properties' to get a list of all properties that an object has.
Is there a way to get a list of only the properties that are observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [metaclass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html) information, and look for the properties that have the `SetObservable` [attribute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html):

```
mc = meta.class.fromName('MyClass');
idx = [mc.PropertyList.SetObservable];
pnames = {mc.PropertyList.Name};
pnames = pnames(idx)
```

Same can be done for `GetObservable` attribute

Comment: you can use [metaclass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/metaclass.html) function if you already have an object of the class